# Execute php script from Python script

Tags: php, python

Here I'm trying to execute a PHP script using Python but I get

> Error : php not found

Should I have to install lammp(I'm using lubuntu 16.04) or is there any way to execute it directly without doing installation?

Here is my Python Script for calling php script.

```
import subprocess
#subprocess.call(["php", "textcleaner.php","bill.jpg out.jpg"])
proc = subprocess.Popen("php textcleaner.php, src.jpg", shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
script_response = proc.stdout.read()
```

Comment: How would you execute php if you dont't have it installed

Answer (score 0):

You must install PHP to execute php scripts on your system.

Answer (score 0):

Either you don't have php installed or your python can't call the php library without a direct link.

If you don't have it installed you need to install it

```
apt-get install php5 libapache2-mod-php5
```

Or if you do have it installed change `php` to `/usr/bin/php`

Comment: I tried to install php5 as You told but it not works .Here what error I got                                                                                                              E: Package 'php5' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'libapache2-mod-php5' has no installation candidate

Comment: Ok i got it  the problem is that Ubuntu 16.04 has switched to PHP 7.0 with a new infrastructure for PHP package(http://askubuntu.com/questions/756879/cant-install-php5-on-ubuntu-16-04) . Thank-You for help.

Comment: Try this: `sudo apt-get install php7.0`